Intellij, Code With Me: Is there any way to desactivate follow me when the host of the session starts to debug?
When me and my coding partner code, when i'm the host of the CWM,he isalways forced to follow me when i am debuging the code on my computer. Is there any way to desactivate this?
I watched the documentation but couldn't find nothing

In case "following" mode is not enabled for you, debugging should not force the following. Please create an issue for this case at:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/search/CWM

Link throws a 404, think you mean https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/CWM ?
